What could cause a gap in the AWS Elastic Beanstalks TargetResponseTime metric, given the service was still responding?
We were investigating an anomaly in our number of completed operations yesterday and of course checked our AWS metrics. We use Elastic Beanstalk to run a key component of our system and its service metrics are really puzzling us. In particular, the gap in the target response time (see image below).
We were still successfully processing at least some operations in that period - you can see a dip in the request count, and that's roughly reflective of the number of successful operations, so it's not like the service completely stopped responding. I would have expected to see a spike (or something else interesting), rather than the data simply being missing.
I would be very grateful if, as well as giving a cause for the odd metric, you could suggest how we might dig deeper into the issue.


Your network in and out metrics are also 0 during that time. It looks like there may have been some sort of networking at AWS during that time.

@MarkB You can't see it in that image, but they weren't quite zero, they were <10KB. Unlike Target response time, which just cuts off. (Plus our logs say stuff was still happening, just around 50% less frequently than usual.)

It's definitely an extreme drop in network IO though. I still think it was some sort of network outage, or some other type of service outage, at AWS. I've seen similar gaps before in CloudWatch metrics that appeared to be some sort of outage or down-time for an AWS service.
